# Is it possible to change opacity of an application window?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to change the opacity/alpha value of a program window such as preview or chrome? I know this was possible in Linux by editing some gnome shell file. Is there anything similar in OS X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**afloat**](https://github.com/vjt/afloat). This allows you to set the opacity of a window from the Window menu.

Answer (score 13):

> **Edit: Dec 2018:** It seems that a new replacement for Afloat is out called Deskovery,
>   You should enter your email here to join the beta program: 
>   https://www.neomobili.com/products/deskovery/
>   And browse the blog to figure out which beta version you want: https://www.neomobili.com/blog/
>   Downloads for all versions of this app are kind of hidden here: https://www.neomobili.com/files/

The previously mentioned Afloat is not working anymore on El Capitan and Sierra since both deprecate applications using code injection techniques.

There seems to be no direct equivalent for this [SIMBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMBL) using Afloat.

If you now need just a 'mock version', does a mock picture suffice your needs? These needs are a bit underdetermined.

However, you may find a number of possible alternatives available that might offer a somewhat similar functionality:

- [LayerX](http://yuhua-chen.github.io/LayerX/)
- [Duplicate-any-windows](http://fabiancanas.com/software/duplicate-windows)
- [Overlay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overlay/id653092846)
- [Overlay2](http://www.colinthomas.com/overlay/)
- [Uberlayer](http://www.twelvetwenty.nl)
- [GluePrint](http://glueprintapp.com)

These are not tested as to whether they may be combinable.

Comment: For those who are looking to compared image mockups to an app you are buiilding, and thus looking for a transparent image window, LayerX seems useful.

Comment: Duplicate-any-windows does not seem applicable to this question, though I understand why it was included.

Comment: LayerX is probably better than Deskovery

Comment: LayerX has a big advantage over Deskovery - it does one thing and one thing well. You can only have transparent images, but I think that's the primary use case here.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work anymore for Chrome too. Been using it before, but now it just doesn't appear on chrome again

Answer (score 0):

The question is about setting the opacity for a single application, but to globally set transparency off, go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display.  Then make sure that "Reduce transparency" is selected. I found this here:
https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/reduce-transparency-effects-os-x-yosemite/
for Yosemite, but it works in El Capitan.

Comment: irrelevant answer! downvote

Comment: @Shorin, thanks for not actually downvoting (yet).  I don't expect upvotes, but to me, it's a service to the community to include a closely related answer that kind of does the same thing, since people will find this question when they are looking for the answer I give.

Comment: Message to downvoters:  Have at it--I'll take the hit.  I still think my four lines of text at the bottom of the answer list doesn't hurt anything, and will help someone--maybe already has.  (This kind of thing not uncommon, actually, in some corners of SE, and those answers often get upvoted.)